# What is strong function and weak function.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, asymptotics, terminology

One of our professors told us that in an expression like $xe^x$ or $x+e^x$ the function behaves like $e^x$ rather than $x$ in the long run i.e. for larger $x$. He told that this dominance is because $e^x$ is a strong function w.r.t. any linear function. Is there any formal definition or rule to determine which function will dominate in a general case?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: $e^x$ dominates $x$ because $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}x=\infty$$ You can apply this logic to any pair of functions to determine what dominates what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, polynomials dominate logarithmic functions, exponentials dominate polynomials, and factoials dominate exponentials.

That is  as $x$ gets very large, the absolute value of the  ratio of the  dominating function over the weaker one goes to infinity.

For example $$\lim _{x\to \infty } \frac  {e^x}{x^2+3x+5}
 =\infty$$ 
$$\lim _{n\to \infty } \frac  {n!}{3^n}
 =\infty$$

Comment: Is there any branch of mathematics that specially discusses about these dominance and what is the most general theory?