# What is a fairly strong function?

Tags: functions, definition

I am reading the [Chapter 7](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9781845692704500077) where one can find the Eq. (7.17):

$$
\frac{Rn^0 Z(\rho_{sys}, T_{ref})T_{ref}}{\rho_{sys}(T_{ref}, T_s)} - V_{ref}=V_1 + \frac{Z(\rho_{sys}, T_{ref})T_{ref}}{Z(\rho_{sys}, T_s)T_s}V_2.
$$

and after the Eq. (7.17) the some weaknesses were denoted, one of than is:

> Third, to accurately delineate $V_1$ and $V_2$, the coefficient of $V_2$ in Eq. (7.17) must be a fairly strong function of temperature, either through a wide range of scanned values for $T_s$ or through a rapidly varying compressibility.

**Question.** What does mean  *a fairly strong function* mathematically here?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue and the found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399123/what-is-strong-function-and-weak-function).

Shortly, a function $f(x)$ seems to be called "stronger" than $g(x)$ iff:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \infty$$

In English, a function is "stronger" if it grows faster than another function with respect to its dependent variable.

The converse is true for the "weaker" comparison.